# writing a Select query to deduct one table from another

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I am just a little confuse to how write the below query :

I have two tables

```
tbl_one
ID      TEXT
1       test1
2       test2
3       test3
4       test4
5       test5
```

and

```
tbl_two
ID      userID      tblone_ID
1       50          1
2       100         1
3       100         2
```

I am looking to get rows of tbl_one which are not appear in tbl_two but for the certain user .

for example by below select  :

```
select * from tbl_one, tbl_two 
where (tbl_two.tblone_ID !=tbl_one.ID and tbl_two.userID==50)
```

my desire resault will be

```
Desire resalt:
ID      TEXT
2       test2
3       test3
4       test4
5       test5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableA a
        LEFT JOIN tableB b
          on a.ID = b.tblone_ID AND
              b.userID = 50
WHERE   b.tblone_ID IS NULL
```

- [***SQLFiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abf52/6)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from tbl_one 
where ID not in (select tblone_ID 
                 from tbl_two 
                 where userID = 50)
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> select * from tbl_one where tbl_one.ID not in ( Select tblone_ID
> FRom tbl_two where userID=50)
>
> SELECT * from tbl_one inner Join tbl_two on tbl_one.ID !=tblone_ID  where userID=50
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_one
LEFT JOIN tbl_two on tbl_one.ID = tbl_two.tblone_ID
WHERE tbl_one.ID IS NULL AND tbl_two.userID = 50
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try this

```
select * from tbl_one t1 
where t1.id not in (select tblone_id from tbl_two where tbl_two.userid=50)
```